# Как в xPath, при поиске, не учитывать пустые узлы?

Tags: xml, xpath

Необходимо найти все изображения, которые являются единственными элементами у своего родителя - ссылки.

Должен находить:

```
<a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" /></a>

<a href="#">    <img src="image.jpg" />    </a>

<a href="#">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</a>
```

Не должен находить:

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
  <img src="image.jpg" />
</a>

<a href="#">
  <img src="image.jpg" />
  Изображение с изображением изображения
</a>

<a href="#"><img src="image.jpg" />Изображение с изображением изображения</a>
```

Вот это условие:

```
//a[count(node())=1][img]
```

...совпадает только с первым примером. Так как (что-то мне подсказывает) принимает пробелы за текстовый узел.

Вроде как, здесь надо использовать две функции: `normalize-space()` и `concat()`. Целый день уже мучаюсь - ничего не получается.

Выручайте, братцы.

Comment: `//a[not(normalize-space()) and count(img)=1]`

Comment: Благодарю!
Объясните, пожалуйста, простыми словами, что это значит: `not(normalize-space())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//a[not(normalize-space()) and count(img)=1]
```

Функция `normalize-space()` удаляет начальные и конечные пробелы из строки и заменяет последовательности пробелов одним пробелом.

В результате, такой XPath:

```
//a[normalize-space()]
```

будет возвращать узлы, *содержащие* какой-либо текст, отличный от пробелов.

Соответственно, такой XPath:

```
//a[not(normalize-space())]
```

будет возвращать узлы, *не содержащие* текст. Одни лишь пробелы за текст не считаются.

Далее остаётся только отфильтровать результат по количеству узлов `img`.